# Can the right column be fixed in the bootstrap-vue table?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I want right fixed columns in the bootstrap-vue table
but, the Sticky function in the document is only fixed to the left.
Is there a way to fix the right side or last columns?

I want both the left and right columns being fixed in place.

documnet : https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#sticky-columns

[image]

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="mb-2">
      <b-form-checkbox v-model="stickyHeader" inline>Sticky header</b-form-checkbox>
      <b-form-checkbox v-model="noCollapse" inline>No border collapse</b-form-checkbox>
    </div>
    <b-table
      :sticky-header="stickyHeader"
      :no-border-collapse="noCollapse"
      responsive
      :items="items"
      :fields="fields"
    >
      <!-- We are using utility class `text-nowrap` to help illustrate horizontal scrolling -->
      <template #head(id)="scope">
        <div class="text-nowrap">Row ID</div>
      </template>
      <template #head()="scope">
        <div class="text-nowrap">
          Heading {{ scope.label }}
        </div>
      </template>
    </b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        stickyHeader: true,
        noCollapse: false,
        fields: [
          { key: 'id', stickyColumn: true, isRowHeader: true, variant: 'primary' },
          'a',
          'b',
          { key: 'c', stickyColumn: true, variant: 'info' },
          'd',
          'e',
          'f',
          'g',
          'h',
          'i',
          'j',
          'k',
          'l'
        ],
        items: [
          { id: 1, a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3, e: 4, f: 5, g: 6, h: 7, i: 8, j: 9, k: 10, l: 11 },
          { id: 2, a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3, e: 4, f: 5, g: 6, h: 7, i: 8, j: 9, k: 10, l: 11 },
          { id: 3, a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3, e: 4, f: 5, g: 6, h: 7, i: 8, j: 9, k: 10, l: 11 },
          { id: 4, a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3, e: 4, f: 5, g: 6, h: 7, i: 8, j: 9, k: 10, l: 11 },
          { id: 5, a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3, e: 4, f: 5, g: 6, h: 7, i: 8, j: 9, k: 10, l: 11 },
          { id: 6, a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3, e: 4, f: 5, g: 6, h: 7, i: 8, j: 9, k: 10, l: 11 },
          { id: 7, a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3, e: 4, f: 5, g: 6, h: 7, i: 8, j: 9, k: 10, l: 11 },
          { id: 8, a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3, e: 4, f: 5, g: 6, h: 7, i: 8, j: 9, k: 10, l: 11 },
          { id: 9, a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3, e: 4, f: 5, g: 6, h: 7, i: 8, j: 9, k: 10, l: 11 },
          { id: 10, a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3, e: 4, f: 5, g: 6, h: 7, i: 8, j: 9, k: 10, l: 11 }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible by overriding bootstrap's CSS with some of our own.  First make sure the last column has the `stickyColumn: true` option plus whatever other options you want to give it:

```js
...
'i',
'j',
'k',
{ key: "l", stickyColumn: true, isRowHeader: true, variant: "primary" },
```

This will ensure it has a classname we can easily select on. Apply styling that gives the last sticky column in the table an attribute of `right: 0`:

```html
<style>
.b-table-sticky-column:last-child {
  right: 0;
}
</style>
```

[codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-goodall-khiv1h?file=/src/App.vue:3658-3724)